# How to set an application variable on application startup

Tags: c#, iis

I try to set an Application object in a class of type IProcessHostPreloadClient (code is running on application initialization, explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795265/IIS-Asp-net-warm-up-Auto-Start-Application):

```
public class DeserializeEdocsProvider : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient 
{
    public void Preload(string[] parameters)
    {
        ... 
            //the following fails with message:
            //"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
            HttpContext.Current.Application["testtest"] = "test";
        ...
    }
}
```

All I want is to create an object when the application starts (after recycle of application pool), and access the object later, in other requests to the web application. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Have a static variable, say `MyVar`, inside a class, say `MyClass`, and set the value inside the `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax`. Later, access the variable with `MyClass.MyVar`.

Comment: Thank you, @mshsayem. Your solution helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a static variable/property, say `MyVar`, inside your class, say `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    private static int _myVariable; 
    public static int MyVar {get; set;} 
    ...
}
```

Now, set the value inside the `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax` (if `Global.asax` is not there add one):

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    MyClass.MyVar = 100;
    ...
}
```

Later, access the variable from anywhere (it is a public static property):

```
...
lblMyLabel.Text = MyClass.MyVar.ToString();
...
```